# Fix sexam package

Tags: polyglossia, exam

This package is a modified version of the "exam" package, compatible with the Arabic language (via XeLaTeX/polyglossia) for exams

In the link there are the package files, but no one worked.
https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/sexam

could one fix the problem?

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{bacex}
%--------------------info---------------------
\newcommand{\alg}{\bf الجمهورية الجزائرية الديمقراطية الشعبية}
\newcommand{\gov}{\bf وزارة التربية الوطنية \hfill   الديوان الوطني للامتحانات و المسابقات}
\newcommand{\bac}{\bf امتحـان بكالوريا التعليم الثانوي 
  \hfill 
   دورة :  
جوان 2017
}
\newcommand{ \duree }{\bf المدة :}
\newcommand{ \niveau }{\bf 
الشعبة : 
تقني رياضي }
\newcommand{ \exam }{\bf اختبار في مادة : }
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document} 
%---------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{center}
\alg  
\\
\gov 
\\
\bac
\end{center}
{\niveau}

\rule{\textwidth}{1.4pt}\\[-2pt]
\centerline{ \exam 
الرياضيات
  \hfill  
\duree 
04 سا و 30 د }\\[-8pt]
\rule{\textwidth}{1.4pt}
%----------------------------------------------
\choi   %           اختيار الموضوعين
\\
%---------------------------------------
\one              % الموضوع  الأول
%----------------------------------------------
\vspace{0.6cm}
%--------------------------------------------------
\begin{questions}

\question [04]    %التمرين الأول
الفضاء منسوب إلى المعلم المتعامد المتجانس 
$\left(O;\overrightarrow{i};\overrightarrow{j};\overrightarrow{k}\right)$ 
.
\\

نعتبر النقط 
$A(0;-1;2)$
،
$B(3;2;5)$
،
$C(3;-1;-1)$
و
$D(-3;5;-1)$
\\

ليكن 
$(P)$
و
$(Q)$
المستويين اللذان معادلتاهما على الترتيب :
$x+y+z-1=0$
و
$x-z+2=0$
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post a `MWE` of your code?

Comment: I didn't do any code, am still trying to run the package files. just the PDF files work. I mean could you run the sexam_wexam_doc_ar.tex for example.

Comment: don't just say "it doesn't work" show the exact error from the log file, For me in texlive2020 your example worked without error except I don't have the font so I got `! Package fontspec Error: The font "Simplified Arabic" cannot be found.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle , I turned the code on TeXstudio but didn't get me-result- just waiting!!!!, then I tried to run the code on TeXWork , was fine-no errors-. but the question now is  why didn't the TeXstudio work?

Comment: @MamounMohammed texstudip and texworks are simply text editors they do not affect the errors that are produced by tex but you may have the paths set up so latex doesn't start properly from texstudio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example works without error in texlive other than the font `Simplified Arabic` is not available (to me at least) so you get the error

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Simplified Arabic" cannot be found.
```

three times. You could edit a local copy to use a font that you do have, or as below locally redefine the font declaration so the font definition in the `bacex` package is ignored.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic,Scale=0.8]{Arial}
\let\zz\newfontfamily
\def\newfontfamily#1[#2]#3{}
\usepackage{bacex}
\let\newfontfamily\zz
%--------------------info---------------------
\newcommand{\alg}{\bf الجمهورية الجزائرية الديمقراطية الشعبية}
\newcommand{\gov}{\bf وزارة التربية الوطنية \hfill   الديوان الوطني للامتحانات و المسابقات}
\newcommand{\bac}{\bf امتحـان بكالوريا التعليم الثانوي 
  \hfill 
   دورة :  
جوان 2017
}
\newcommand{ \duree }{\bf المدة :}
\newcommand{ \niveau }{\bf 
الشعبة : 
تقني رياضي }
\newcommand{ \exam }{\bf اختبار في مادة : }
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document} 
%---------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{center}
\alg  
\\
\gov 
\\
\bac
\end{center}
{\niveau}

\rule{\textwidth}{1.4pt}\\[-2pt]
\centerline{ \exam 
الرياضيات
  \hfill  
\duree 
04 سا و 30 د }\\[-8pt]
\rule{\textwidth}{1.4pt}
%----------------------------------------------
\choi   %           اختيار الموضوعين
\\
%---------------------------------------
\one              % الموضوع  الأول
%----------------------------------------------
\vspace{0.6cm}
%--------------------------------------------------
\begin{questions}

\question [04]    %التمرين الأول
الفضاء منسوب إلى المعلم المتعامد المتجانس 
$\left(O;\overrightarrow{i};\overrightarrow{j};\overrightarrow{k}\right)$ 
.
\\

نعتبر النقط 
$A(0;-1;2)$
،
$B(3;2;5)$
،
$C(3;-1;-1)$
و
$D(-3;5;-1)$
\\

ليكن 
$(P)$
و
$(Q)$
المستويين اللذان معادلتاهما على الترتيب :
$x+y+z-1=0$
و
$x-z+2=0$
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I used Arial here: I can not read this script but it hopefully looks as intended.

[image]